# Align columns properly in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I want to sort Excel columns in a particular way that I'm having trouble figuring out, but I know there should be a simple solution.

I have 4 columns:

- Column A is a hostname, column B is its corresponding IP address. Some of these address fields are null, however.
- Column C is the same list of IPs, but they are not aligned with Column B.
- Column D has information about the IPs in Column C.

I want Column C and D to align with the first 2, leaving C and D blank for every null field in Column B.

```
Problem:
Col B  Col C&D   
  A      A   
  B      C   
  C      D  
  D      E   
  E

Desired Outcome:
Col B  Col C&D  
  A      A  
  B     
  C      C  
  D      D  
  E      E
```

Comment: Sooo.... what's the question? It would be less confusing if you could clearly state what you've tried, and where the problem is. Sample data and expected outcome may also be useful

Comment: Sorry, let me see if I can make it simpler: I've edited it and hopefully I'm making sense now

Comment: If you want to re-order columns `C:C` and `D:D` in place, this would require a VBA solution. For a formula only solution, you will need two extra columns. The actual formulas are a simple `VLOOKUP` with a null check.

Comment: You mention sorting.  Is the problem that you're sorting and the columns aren't aligned when you're done, or the columns are independent and you need to align them?  If the problem is sorting, you need to select the whole matrix before you sort in order to keep rows aligned.  If you're trying to align independent columns, you can use a lookup of col C against col B in some new columns.  If you can clarify the situation, people can offer solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks robinCTS,

I was able to solve this problem with a vlookup. Ultimately, it is not exactly what I was trying to achieve, but probably more efficient anyway. Here is the formula I was able to use, for anyone else who may run into this problem:

=(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B1,$D$1:$E$168,2,FALSE)," "))